# confused on how to get another row from a query that's returning a specific set of values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I downloaded some code that utilizes PDO, which I'm not too familiar with - I generally use mysqli_ statements, but I'm trying to learn how to use PDO as well.

In the following bit of code, a user begins to type a part number into a field, and the system returns any value from the database's`quotePartNumber`field that is LIKE what they're typing in.

```
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql              = "SELECT DISTINCT quotePartNumber from allparts where quotePartNumber LIKE (:keyword) LIMIT 0,10";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text 
  $country_name = str_replace(strtoupper($_POST['keyword']), '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['quotePartNumber']);

    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_mainPartNumber(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['quotePartNumber']).'\')">'.$country_name.'</li>';
}
```

This works perfectly... I've been playing around with the code for about two hours trying to figure out how to get it to ALSO pull the field`supplier`, which is also in this same table.

When the user starts typing in a part number, I also want the supplier that matches up with that same row's part number to be returned.  I can't figure out how to do it though...

any ideas?

Comment: Remove Distinct and add supplier to the list of fields?

Comment: You could get rid of the DISTINCT function and use something like GROUP B, like SELECT supplier, quotePartNumber FROM allparts GROUP BY(quotePartNumber)

Comment: yeah - it's the "add supplier to the list of fields" part that I can't figure out how to do.......

Comment: @Peter I'm confused by this... I need to use distinct because there could be multiple instances of the same part number, so I only want to display each one once - or else when someone types "a", they may get the same part number 10 times instead of 10 different part numbers that all have "a" in them.  Why can't I just take the corresponding 'supplier' field from the 'quotePartNumber' field that is returned?

Comment: Sorry about that, guess I was to quick with my comment. As shown below you should simply add the required field to the query.

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as changing the select statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT quotePartNumber, supplier from allparts where quotePartNumber LIKE (:keyword) LIMIT 0,10";
```

Then you could display it by updating the echo statement.

```
 echo '<li onclick="set_mainPartNumber(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['quotePartNumber']).'\')">'.$country_name.' - '.$rs['supplier'].'</li>';
```

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I needed.... I was trying to do this in a way more complicated manner!  Thank you so much.